# Ejabberd Impersonation

Tags: c#, xmpp, impersonation, ejabberd

I am using ejabberd 2 with Jabber-net. I want to ask you if it's possible to impersonate a user when logging in with the admin. Meaning i want to able to login with the admin account and send a message **From: 'User A'**, **To: 'User B'** ? When i try to do that the server returns

```
<stream:error xmlns:stream=\"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams\">
<invalid-from xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams\" />
</stream:error>
```

Thank you for the spared time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a XMPP console client and you login as UserA (meaning you know the password or have no password requirement access method in another environment than production), you can send the stanza through that console "impersonating" an specific user.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use Pidgin or Spark. Both of them have an excellent xmpp console to send your custom stanzas.